# AWS Codedploy Agent Access denied from EC2 instance to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I have set up the Codedeploy Agent, however when I run it, I get the error:

```
Error: HEALT_CONSTRAINTS
```

By going further , this is the entry in the code deploy log from the EC2 instance:

```
InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Cannot reach InstanceService: Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied - Access Denied
```

I have done a simple `wget` from the bucket and it results:

```
Connecting to s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com (s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com)|xxxxxxxxx|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
```

On the opposite, if I use the AWS cli I can correctly reach the S3 bucket.

The EC2 instance is on a VPC, it has a role associated with full permission on S3, firewall settings inbound and outbound seem correct. So it is obviously something related to permissions in accessing from https.

The questions:

1. Under which credentials Code Deploy Agent runs ?
2. What permissions or roles have to be set on S3 bucket ?

Comment: If you use the CLI on that instance (not locally) can you download an object from the code deployment bucket?

Comment: Well, I have checked better, I cannot download the object using CLI on the EC2 instance. I can download any other objects from other S3 buckets, but not from the one where the artifact is.

Answer (score 2):

The EC2 instance's credentials (the instance role) will be used when pulling from S3.

To be clear, the Service Role that CodeDeploy needs does not need S3 permissions. The ServiceRole CodeDeploy needs allows CodeDeploy to call AutoScaling & EC2 APIs to describe the instances so CodeDeploy knows how to deploy to them.

That being said, for your AccessDenied issue for S3, there are 2 things you need to check

- The role that the EC2 instance(s) has `s3:Get*` and `s3:List*` (or more specific) permissions
- The S3 bucket you want to deploy has a policy attached that allows the EC2 instance role to get the object.

Documentation for permissions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/instances-ec2-configure.html#instances-ec2-configure-2-verify-instance-profile-permissions

Answer (score 0):

CodeDeploy uses "Service Roles" to access AWS resoures. In the AWS console for CodeDeploy, look for "Service role". Assign the IAM role that you created for CodeDeploy in your application settings.

If you have not created a IAM role for CodeDeploy, do so and then assign it to your CodeDeploy application.